# Python how to accept multiple arguments on add magic method

Tags: python

I'm trying to play around with operator overloading, and i found myself trying more than 2 arguments. How would I implement this to accept any number of arguments.

```
class Dividend:

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount

    def __add__(self, other_investment):
        return self.amount + other_investment.amount

investmentA = Dividend(150)
investmentB = Dividend(50)
investmentC = Dividend(25)

print(investmentA + investmentB) #200
print(investmentA + investmentB + investmentC) #error
```

Comment: You would return a new instance of `Dividend` from `__add__` to do this, normally.

Comment: Afaik you can not do it that way: `investmentA + investmentB + investmentC` is interpreted as `(investmentA + investmentB) + investmentC`...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not that your `__add__` method doesn't accept multiple arguments, the problem is that it does not return a `Dividend`. The addition operator is always a binary operator, but after the first addition you end up trying to add a numeric type to a `Dividend` rather than adding two dividends. You should have your `__add__` method return the appropriate type, for example:

```
def __add__(self, other_investment):
    return Dividend(self.amount + other_investment.amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always pass in multiple objects as a list and loop through them. This will return an integer type.

> ```
> class Dividend:
>
>     def __init__(self, amount):
>         self.amount = amount
>
>     def __add__(self, other_investment):
>         for e in other_investment:
>             self.amount +=e.amount
>         return self.amount
>
> investmentA = Dividend(150)
> investmentB = Dividend(50)
> investmentC = Dividend(25)
>
> print(investmentA + [investmentB]) #200
> print((investmentA + [investmentB, investmentC])) #not an error
> ```

Output:

200

275